# Numpy to check if a solution exists such that each row is < 0?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

Consider the following code

```
X=np.matrix([[1,-1,1],[-1,0,1]])

print X.T
'''
[[ 1 -1]
 [-1  0]
 [ 1  1]]
'''
```

I want to check if a solution exists where the transpose has a <0 solution. For example this would mean checking if the following has a solution

```
1*y1 + -1*y2 < 0
-1*y1 + 0*y2 < 0
1*y1 + 1*y2 < 0
```

Tried reading http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve but apparently no such luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the documentation you need:

[numpy apply along axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
import numpy as np:
def func(b,y1,y2):
    a = b.T
    if a[0]*y1 + a[1]*y2 < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
np.apply_along_axis(func,0,X,y1,y2)
```

so now let's say you want y1 as -1 and y2 as 3:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(func,0,X,-1,3)
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

so this means on transpose the first row (which would be the normal first column) works with your algorithm, the second and third do not!

this is a function for an arbitrary number of Ys as in as large of a matrix as you want:

```
def func(b,*args):
    a = b.T
    total = [a[i]*args[i] for i in range(len(args)-1)]
    if sum(total) < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Inconsistent? What do you mean?

Comment: This also does not do what I need it to do

Comment: you just edited it so it is no longer inconsistent. you had `-1*y1 - 0*y2 < 0` and it didn't make sense, but you fixed it so now I get what you want, i'll edit it

Comment: now I edited it since I knew what you meant with an example that shows it works

Comment: Does this work with X of any size? I am confused what the arguments mean

Comment: what are you confused about, I'll add comments explaining the lines

Comment: but I mean this is basically hard-checking values of y1 and y2 via brute force, correct?

Comment: it is writing a function that will run through the matrix and check for each line if it matches what you are checking for. Also, if you want this for an arbitrary number of values, you can do that with a loop as long as the number of Yx is equal to the number of items in the transposed rows. Is that true? cuz then I can add an edit

Comment: Brute force is good.   @Ryan Saxe: if I understand your code you are doing a 1-d search.  If the y's are N-d he will need to have N-1 different y's.   Or you could extend your code to do an arbitrary N-2 dimensional search.

Comment: In my case the X's can be any length but always 2 vectors in total (so the transpose will just be a bunch of ay1 + by2 equations, number of equations dictated by length of X). Sorry for not clarifying this before

Comment: in that case, then the first equation will work for any size of `X`!

Comment: So how would I use it though? Just iterate over a arbitrary range of y1 and an arbitrary range of y2 and test each one?

Comment: no, the function takes 3 inputs, a numpy array, and y1 and y2. when you use: `np.apply_along_axis(func,0,X,y1,y2)` it says apply the function `func` to the array `x` with inputs `y1` and `y2` and it iterates that through each row you have

Comment: Right but I mean if I am just checking to see if there is at least one solution, I have to feed it values for y1 and y2 correct? So something like

    for y1 in range(-10,11):
        for y2 in range(-10,11):
            ans = np.apply_along_axis(func,0,X,y1,y2)
            if set(ans)==set([True]): return False'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your question is equivalent to asking if the plane that contains the origin and also vectors `U=r_[1,-1,1]` and `V=r_[-1, 0, 1]` extends into the octant of 3-d space where all coords are negative.

The cross product `UxV` (or `cross(U,V)` is normal to this plane.  If this cross-product has three nonzero components all of the same sign, then none of the the normals from it can be in the dreaded octant.  For the case of your numbers, I get all three components negative, so there is no solution.

**[UPDATE]**

In general, the tricky things happen when the normal contains zeros:

*Three-zeros*:  Your original vectors are parallel,  or one of them is zero.  Pick one that is not zero and if all components have the same sign, then you have a solution.

*Two-zeros*: Your plane is one of X=0, Z=0, Y=0.  Thus one dimension is always nonnegative, there are no solutions.

*One-zero*: Your plain includes the X, Y or Z axis.  There is a solution if and only if the remaining two components of the normal have differing signs.

Comment: Is there a general way to check for this? When I try this method, it says the cross method doesn't work if one piece is length 1, and sometimes it only gives me a single True or False vs. a set of True/False values

Comment: And this also doesn't work if the length is greater than 3 either, for example U=[-1, 1, 1, -1] V=[0, 1, 0, -1]

Comment: The cross product only works for 3-vectors.  There are generalisations to other dimensions (read about [Levi-Civita symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)), and I suspect that checking the signs of the resulting tensors will help.  But I haven't thought about this in detail.